# How to replace ereg?

Tags: php, regex, pcre, posix-ere

I'm getting the following message for some php I have to use but did not write:

```
Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated in /opt/lampp/htdocs/webEchange/SiteWeb_V5/inc/html2fpdf.php on line 466
```

This is line 466:

```
if(ereg('^([^=]*)=["\']?([^"\']*)["\']?$',$v,$a3))
```

I tried simply replacing with preg_match, but it couldn't recognize the = modifier in the regular expression.. I'm not too good with regular expression yet and solving this requires that I learn the regexp ereg needs AND the regexp preg_match needs (which, if I am not mistaken, is different)... Could you guys help me out with this one?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert ereg expressions to preg in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/how-can-i-convert-ereg-expressions-to-preg-in-php)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*POSIX extended regular expressions* (POSIX ERE, used by `ereg`) and *Perl-combatible regular expressions* (PCRE, used by `preg_match`) are very similar. Except from [some special POSIX expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html), PCRE is a superset of POSIX ERE.

That means you just need to put your POSIX ERE regular expressions into [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) (here `/`) and escape any occurrence of that character inside the regular expression and you have a valid PCRE regular expression:

```
/^([^=]*)=["']?([^"']*)["']?$/
```

So:

```
preg_match('/^([^=]*)=["\']?([^"\']*)["\']?$/', $v, $a3)
```

Comment: Not really a superset (besides character classes), e.g. matching `/AB|ABC/` on `ABCD` with ERE will give the longest match (`ABC`) but PCRE will give the first match (`AB`).

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
if(preg_match('~^([^=]*)=["\']?([^"\']*)["\']?$~',$v,$a3))
```

The regex in preg_match needs to be enclosed between a pair of delimiters, which is not the case with the deprecated ereg() function.

Answer (score 1):

Copied by other contributor:

This not is a replace is recover ereg function:

```
if(!function_exists('ereg'))            { function ereg($pattern, $subject, &$matches = []) { return preg_match('/'.$pattern.'/', $subject, $matches); } }
if(!function_exists('eregi'))           { function eregi($pattern, $subject, &$matches = []) { return preg_match('/'.$pattern.'/i', $subject, $matches); } }
if(!function_exists('ereg_replace'))    { function ereg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string) { return preg_replace('/'.$pattern.'/', $replacement, $string); } }
if(!function_exists('eregi_replace'))   { function eregi_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string) { return preg_replace('/'.$pattern.'/i', $replacement, $string); } }
if(!function_exists('split'))           { function split($pattern, $subject, $limit = -1) { return preg_split('/'.$pattern.'/', $subject, $limit); } }
if(!function_exists('spliti'))          { function spliti($pattern, $subject, $limit = -1) { return preg_split('/'.$pattern.'/i', $subject, $limit); } }
```

Comment: What contributor did this come from? And are you saying this _doesn’t_ work? Reading the code, this appears to offer a polyfill for the deprecated functions. Have you tested with the OP’s specific expression?

Answer (score 0):

the `preg_` family expects the regex to be delimited. Instead of:

```
'^([^=]*)=["\']?([^"\']*)["\']?$'
```

try:

```
'/^([^=]*)=["\']?([^"\']*)["\']?$/'
```