# eregi_replace() is deprecated

Tags: php, deprecated, eregi

I have just created a simple word filter for users bios when they are updated.
This is the code:

```
 for($i=0;$i < sizeof($badwords);$i++){
  srand((double)microtime()*1000000); 
  $rand_key = (rand()%sizeof($replacements));
  $str = eregi_replace($badwords[$i], $replacements[$rand_key], $str);
 }
 return $str;



}
```

When I submit the Bio, the text saves however I get this error:

> Deprecated: Function eregi_replace() is deprecated in
>   /home/u557520691/public_html/inc/Global.php on line 177

Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Comment: I get another error: ''Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in...''     when I use preg.

Comment: use `str_replace` for this.

Comment: It sounds like a misuse of regular expressions. I bet `$badwords` are just static words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

[How to replace ereg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217850/how-to-replace-ereg)

or just turn the notice off

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);
```

or

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
```